# Symfony 2 Create a Entity in another Entiy Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

Hi I think there would be a very simple solution for this but I got a little bit stuck here.

I have two entities. An Author and a Poem. As expected one author can write a lot of poems but one poem can only have one author.

Now I have my poem form:

```
class PoemType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder            
     * @param array $options            
     */
    public function buildForm (FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title')
            ->add('authorId')
            ->add('text', 'textarea', 
                array(
                        'attr' => array(
                                'class' => 'tinymce'
                        )
                )
                );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver            
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions (OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
                array(
                        'data_class' => 'Galerie\PictureBundle\Entity\Poem'
                ));
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName ()
    {
        return 'galerie_picturebundle_poem';
    }
}
```

So the user can choose an author for the poem. But I want the possibility that the user can add an author from here. So if he enters a new poem and the author doesn't exist he can add it here.

I already found this [Allowing new tags with the prototype](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) but in my case there is no collection.

Is this possible ?

thanks for your help in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can embed the author form in your poem form. see the documentation for details
http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Comment: This is the solution if I add everey time a new author. But I only sometimes have to add a new author.

Comment: not really, as stated in the docu you can give the key of the object or if not given an entity is created, how you display this to the user is up to you... for example an select field for selecting existing, or on click in a hidden div the author fields, some JS magic and you are done.